# Is this a potential way of making Facebook Login work correctly on installed standalone PWAs on iPhones?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

As far as I can tell, installed PWAs in standalone mode are not able to make full use of Facebook Login on iPhones, which poses a major problem for end users, app owners and developers.

When a user who is currently logged into Facebook taps the “Login with Facebook” button within an installed PWA in standalone mode, instead of opening a Facebook screen that displays the “Continue as [name]” button, they are presented with a Facebook login form in the in-app browser.

Forcing the user to enter their Facebook login credentials fails because

1. most people cannot remember their Facebook login details.
2. it defeats the purpose of Facebook Login, which is meant to be an easy 2-click solution.
3. the in-app browser makes it feel like you’re entering your details into the app itself, not Facebook, which makes people understandably suspicious

I have created and tested a workaround, using the Facebook Devices login method, that overcomes the issue, but there’s a bug.

The workaround is:

- the developer turns on “Login from Devices” in their Facebook Developer account
- when the user hits the “Login with Facebook” button, the app calls https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/device/login and sends it its app id and client token
- the graph returns a long code and a user code
- the app displays the user code, a button that will click through to https://www.facebook.com/device, and brief instructions:

“You login code is...

XXXXXXXX

…copy it, tap the “Enter Code” button below, paste your code, then come back here”

Alternatively the app can copy the code to the clipboard, and display the code, button & following instructions. This is the way I have set it up:

“Your login code…

XXXXXXXX

...has been copied to your clipboard. Tap the Enter Code button below, paste in your code, then come back here.”

- the app begins polling the graph to see if the user has entered the code i.e. for a returned access token (NOTE: polling is done in the app’s service worker so that it continues regardless the user exits the app’s scope in the next step)
- the user hits the ”Enter Code” button. Facebook prompts “How do you want to log in?” and shows the buttons “With the Facebook App” and “With This Browser”. The user chooses “With the Facebook App” (if they choose “With this Browser”, they’re presented with the login form), enters the code and hits the “Continue as [name]” button
- the user’s Apps and Websites section in their Facebook account shows that the app has been approved
- the app receives the access token and logs the user in

The bug is:

If all done from the phone and the  user successfully enters the code and the Apps and Websites section in their Facebook account shows that they’ve approved access, the app doesn’t receive an access token on the first attempt. If the user tries again however, the app DOES receive the token i.e. subsequent attempts work.

On further testing (if the user hasn’t previously approved Facebook Login for the app), if the user instead enters the phone’s code on another device at facebook.com/device e.g. a laptop, the phone DOES receive the token the first time.

I believe this could be a good workaround if the app on the phone is able to receive the token the first time.

Do you have any idea as to why it wouldn’t?

If we can get it to work, it’s not an ideal solution, but I believe it’s still better that forcing users to enter their Facebook login credentials.

Here are two screenshot videos of me hitting the Facebook Login button, then the Enter Code button, entering the code, exiting the Facebook app and returning to my app. They show the debug display of the Facebook graph poll (every 5 seconds)

1. token not being returned and login not successful, regardless the user’s Facebook account shows they’ve approved the app:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sr6-jOhI3Vuqp5FocaLp7MNCNQZVnalo/view?usp=drive_link

2. subsequent attempt works now that the app has been previously approved:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o37FJYjLIB-58V0a9m41Qk84VB6111rO/view?usp=drive_link

Thank you for taking a look